# Android RecycleView list item created when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have learnt how to use RecycleView with existing data, in other others displaying all the data from arrays and displaying it. Now I want to know how can I implement the same idea but instead a button is clicked a new RecyclerView item is created and added to the rest of the list from data that the user inserts in a dialog box?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you gotten stuck? Please review [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidlines on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Sorry, still a newbie to stackoverflow, only used it for reference in the past. I will definitely have a read on that thanks.

I have not gotten stuck, I just dont know where to start.

Comment: No worries, learning to ask the right questions is a big part of learning how to program. I'll post and answer with how to break down the problem.

Comment: Actually there is a good example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845069/add-a-new-item-to-recyclerview-programatically

Comment: Wow, it looks a simplier than I thought, however, the notifyDataSetChanged()

doesnt seem to be accepted.