# Change a view in Recycler view to a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view with a custom layout

The custom layout has a button that updates some information this process takes some time and is done in an AsyncTask

My Question is can i change my custom layout to a ProgressDialog while this operation is taking place on the Selected row item only, and then when it is finished change back to the custom layout ??

Comment: This answer might help you! [Append view to `RecyclerView`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29452807/4935567)

Answer (score 1):

Yes in that case you should implement a progress bar in each row

When second row button is clicked replace button with the progress bar and when operation is finished make progress bar hide so that it will revert to original state

Happy codding!

Comment: I don't think this to be an **efficient** way.